# Dialog box on phones (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery

```
$(function(){
$('.download-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<iframe src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" style="display: none;"></iframe>').prependTo('.download-buttons');
});         //live end
});             //function end
```

Above is my code that triggers when download button is clicked, it is used to display the dialog save file dialog box which works perfectly on desktop browsers but when I click the button using phone doesn't do anything. Since it is mainly for images `jpeg`, What I want it to do is open the image in an window which can saved manually since dialog box in phone is not practical or not possible. Please help.

Comment: may be iframe is not supported on the phone..

Comment: @C-linkNepal, What can I use then as an alternative?

Comment: I saw this mobile dialog [example on the net](http://javascriptbites.com/post/2013/07/01/How-to-open-a-jQuery-Mobile-Dialog-from-javascript) `$.mobile.changePage($(this).attr('href'),{ transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'});` However the mobile must support the mime-type to open/download